# ubuntu 16.04 can't boot after boot repair

Tags: boot-repair

i wanted to extend the disc size using GPart, and i remember deleting the swap area and then changing the boot flag from one disc sda1 to logical sdb6. but i realize i could'nt extend the disc sda1, so i return things the way they were before, i re-enable the swap area and change back the boot flag. but after rebooting my laptop, bios couldn't find bootable device. i tried boot repair but nothing changed, still can't repair it, here is the boot repair URL

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wJ3tj825VZ/

please help, there are very important projects i need to finalize from this PC.

Comment: yes but no luck.

Comment: (If the drives are not encrypted*, you could boot from a live CD and access the drive to copy data off if you need access urgently. Or you could remove the drive and install it into another machine to access it immediately. *It's possible, but more complicated, if they are encrypted.)

Comment: Did deleting and recreating the swap change the partition numbers?

Comment: @SabreWolfy let me try this option

Comment: @SabreWolfy i managed to transfer my projects using this approach. thanks. i decided to reinstall fresh copy of ubuntu 18.04 LTS.